# How to avoid System.OutOfMemoryException in TikaOnDotnet.TextExtractor

Tags: c#, .net, apache-tika

I am using TikaOnDotnet.TextExtractor to extract various types of files. It runs on Windows 10 (x64) as a console application. Sometimes however it throws System.OutOfMemoryException for certain files.

Here is a sample code:

```
using System;
using TikaOnDotNet.TextExtraction;

namespace TikaRnD
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Type IKVM_OpenJDK_A = typeof(com.sun.codemodel.@internal.ClassType);
            Type IKVM_OpenJDK_B = typeof(com.sun.org.apache.xalan.@internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl);

            var textExtractor = new TextExtractor();
            try
            {
                var teResult = textExtractor.Extract(@"c:\Temp\Largefile.docx");
                Console.WriteLine(teResult.Text.Length);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Largefile.docx is ~6MB document with lots of text and embedded images. When it comes to run it I can see that the process starts consuming more and more of system memory. 4GB of RAM is not enough and it ends with the exception:

```
TikaOnDotNet.TextExtraction.TextExtractionException: Extraction of text from the file 'c:\Temp\TestData\Largefile.docx' failed. ---> TikaOnDotNet.TextExtraction.TextExtractionException: Extraction failed. ---> System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
   at org.apache.poi.extractor.ExtractorFactory.createExtractor(OPCPackage pkg)
   at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.ooxml.OOXMLExtractorFactory.parse(InputStream stream, ContentHandler baseHandler, Metadata metadata, ParseContext context)
   at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.ooxml.OOXMLParser.parse(InputStream stream, ContentHandler handler, Metadata metadata, ParseContext context)
   at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(InputStream stream, ContentHandler handler, Metadata metadata, ParseContext context)
   at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(InputStream stream, ContentHandler handler, Metadata metadata, ParseContext context)
   at org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parse(InputStream stream, ContentHandler handler, Metadata metadata, ParseContext context)
   at TikaOnDotNet.TextExtraction.Stream.StreamTextExtractor.Extract(Func`2 streamFactory, Stream outputStream) in C:\projects\tikaondotnet\src\TikaOnDotnet.TextExtractor\Stream\StreamTextExtractor.cs:line 31
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at TikaOnDotNet.TextExtraction.Stream.StreamTextExtractor.Extract(Func`2 streamFactory, Stream outputStream) in C:\projects\tikaondotnet\src\TikaOnDotnet.TextExtractor\Stream\StreamTextExtractor.cs:line 43
   at TikaOnDotNet.TextExtraction.TextExtractor.Extract(Func`2 streamFactory) in C:\projects\tikaondotnet\src\TikaOnDotnet.TextExtractor\TextExtractor.cs:line 53
   at TikaOnDotNet.TextExtraction.TextExtractor.Extract(String filePath) in C:\projects\tikaondotnet\src\TikaOnDotnet.TextExtractor\TextExtractor.cs:line 19
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at TikaOnDotNet.TextExtraction.TextExtractor.Extract(String filePath) in C:\projects\tikaondotnet\src\TikaOnDotnet.TextExtractor\TextExtractor.cs:line 28
   at TikaRnD.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\users\norbert\source\repos\TikaRnD\TikaRnD\Program.cs:line 20
```

When I run the sample code with the same file on the system with more memory it consumes up to ~10GB of RAM and completes extraction successfully - extracted content size is ~50MB.

Could anyone help me to understand why is that ridiculously high memory consumption happening and how to prevent it if possible?

Comment: Set the parser context object to switch to the streaming xlsx reader instead?

Comment: Not a solution but a hint at why this is happening: https://grokbase.com/t/tika/user/125gs83pm5/tika-fails-to-extract-text-from-very-large-files quote `PPT/PPTX, DOC/DOCX and PDF are all formats
which can only be parsed by building a DOM-like structure in memory, so they
need more memory available to them. XLS/XLSX, amongst a few others, can be
done in a largely streaming manner`